# Visual Studio 2008 can't connect to SQL Server 2014 database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to connect my Visual Studio 2008 to my SQL Server 2014 database. But I am getting this error:

> This server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 are supported.

[image]

But when I tried to click "Test Connection" the result will be: "Test Connection succeeded." 
Can anybody there encounter an error like this also? Please help if you know how to solve this error. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

[According to this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/925ca0ee-ad76-4e7c-b996-458203781506/this-version-is-not-supported-only-servers-up-to-microsoft-sql-server-2005-are-supported?forum=vbgeneral) it looks like you might be completely out of luck. I haven't had this exact issue, but I know that between varying releases of SQL Server Management Studio and other MS products there can be headaches galore. Looks like you might have to upgrade/downgrade something in order for them to 'play nice'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so its much better if I'll just used the same version? Or let say I'll use VS 2008 and SQL server management studio 2005?

Comment: In all honesty, yeah just go with 2005. I've had so many frustrating moments with cross-release compatibility. You could also just see what version of SQLSMS is compatible with your Visual Studio.

Comment: As a side note, SQLSMS isn't forward-compatible. So, if you've created a DB in 2014 and expect it to work smoothly in 2005...you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: By the way about this error, I already get this one. you just have to use the connection string to connect to database

Answer (score -3):

Just use OleDB as your database connection